# A difference between Unicode and ASCII operators

Tags: utf-8, operators, ascii, raku

I found out that Unicode and ASCII operators sometimes work differently when  quote-interpolated.

Consider this:

```
$ perl6 -e'my $a = BagHash.new: <a a a a b b b c c c c c d>;for $a.keys -> $k { say "$k => $a<<$k>>" }'

d => 1
b => 3
c => 5
a => 4
```

and this:

```
$ perl6 -e'my $a = BagHash.new: <a a a a b b b c c c c c d>;for $a.keys -> $k { say "$k => $a«$k»" }'

c => c(5) a(4) b(3) d«c»
a => c(5) a(4) b(3) d«a»
b => c(5) a(4) b(3) d«b»
d => c(5) a(4) b(3) d«d»
```

But this works even when using an Unicode operator:

```
$ perl6 -e'my $a = BagHash.new: <a a a a b b b c c c c c d>;for $a.keys -> $k { say "$k => {$a«$k»}" }'
d => 1
b => 3
a => 4
c => 5
```

Is this a bug, or there's an explanation I can't see?

Comment: Feels like a bug to me.

Comment: Also, we currently refer to these as "Unicode" and "ASCII" operators, afaik.

Comment: Thanks @ElizabethMattijsen : s/UTF-8/Unicode/

Comment: Rakduo issue for this question: [2825](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/2825)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to be fixed with [commit 2835](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/2835)  from MasterDuke17:

```diff
  sub bracket_ending($matches) {
      my $check     := $matches[+$matches - 1];
      my str $str   := $check.Str;
      my $last  := nqp::substr($str, nqp::chars($check) - 1, 1);
-     $last eq ')' || $last eq '}' || $last eq ']' || $last eq '>'
+     $last eq ')' || $last eq '}' || $last eq ']' || $last eq '>' || $last eq '»'
  }
```